# Kibana - Group by and get latest record in each group

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-6

I'm trying to create a table visualisation in Kibana which groups by a field (`computerName`), and just shows the *latest* record in that group.

In the 'Dev Tools' window, the following query gives me what I want...

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "latest_settings": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "computerName.keyword",
        "size": 3
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_sales_hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "timestamp": {
                  "order": "desc"
                }
              }
            ],
            "_source": {
              "includes": [
                "settings.Setting1",
                "settings.Setting2",
                "settings.Setting3"
              ]
            },
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can't see how to do the same query in the Visualisation editor though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Terms` aggregation on `computerName` for the X axis and `Top Hit` metric for Y axis. You can set the `sort` in Kibana UI but you will have to use `Advanced > JSON input` for `_source`